# ООП и удаление с бд

Tags: веб-программирование, php, ооп

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in /* on line 20

в чем накололся?(

```
<?

mysql_connect ("*","","*"); mysql_select_db ("") or die(mysql_error());

class delete { public $id; public $dateBase; public $sd;

public function delete_drop(){

$this->sd = mysql_query("DELETE FROM `messages_room` WHERE `id`=' ".$this->id." '  ");
return $this->sd;
}

$delete_Class = new delete(); //ошибка 
$delete_Class->id = $_POST['q']; 
$delete_Class->dateBase ="messages_room";

echo $delete_Class->delete_drop();

unset($delete_Class);

?>
```

Новая проблема(

Всем спасибо заработало!)

Comment: устанавливаете `dateBaseTwo` вместо `dateBase`.

Comment: @Etki, да тут, наверное, до установки дело и не доходит: метод где заканчивается? И потом - что такое `$this->sd`?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION in**** on line 20
$delete_Class = new delete(); //ошибка

Comment: в чем проблема?((

Comment: @Dminko93 вы метод правильно закройте, после `return $this->sd;` поставьте закрывающую фигурную скобку, я же выше про это писал - у вас нет конца метода (ну либо класса)

Comment: @Dminko93, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

`$this->sd` - если используете обращение внутри класса ($this) то надо объявить в начале `public $sd;`.

`$delete_Class->dateBaseTwo` - может всё таки просто `$delete_Class->dateBase` ?
Да и по логике, Вы же обращаетесь не к базе а к таблице. рекомендую переименовать на $this->tableName.

`id=".$this->id."` - добавьте одинарные кавычки для переменной `' ".$this->id." '` .

Если есть сомнения в выполнении SQL запроса добавьте вывод ошибок - `mysql_query("тут запрос") or die(mysql_error());`

```
class delete { 
    public $id;
    public $tableName;

public function delete_drop(){
    // Создавать объект стоит если Вы ещё где то собираетесь использовать. В противном случае достаточно обычной внутренней переменной для возврата результата.
    $query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ".$this->tableName." WHERE `id` = '".$this->id."' ");
    return $query;
}

$delete_Class = new delete; 
$delete_Class->id = (int)$_POST['q']; // Так как по правилам хорошего тона id это целое число то приводим его на случай попытки Sql-инъекции к инту.
$delete_Class->tableName = "messages_room";

echo $delete_Class->delete_drop(); // Выведет или true -в случае удачного удаления, или false в случае невыполнения запроса.

unset($delete_Class);
```

Comment: 1. необязательно - public присваивается автоматически. Эта переменная нигде не используется, а значит там this на фиг не нужен. Да и вообще какие паблики? ("необязательно" - потому что не ошибка, но по хорошему надо, конечно, объявлять)

3. Ели id - это число, то тогда тоже не обязательно (главное перед этим intval сделать, чтоб наверняка)

4. Иногда намного полезнее вывести сам запрос и ручками его выполнить в консоли (хотя бы через explain)

ЗЫ. Может покажете ребенку как должен был класс выглядеть? А то я ленивый страшно )))

Comment: Подправил ответ. Иногда проще сделать самому чем объяснять :-)
public присваивается автоматически для совместимости кода написанного под старые версии php в котором ещё не была реализована инкапсуляция. Нужно с самого начала учиться писать правильно.